# scrot: failed to save image: test.png: No saver for file format

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.6, pyautogui

I have installed scrot in RHEL 7.9.
When I try to screenshot, scrot does not work with a below message.

```
>scrot test.png
scrot: failed to save image: test.png: No saver for file format
```

I'm local user of this computer and don't have sudo previlege.
I'm already installed imlib2 and lipng to solve this problem.
But it does not work. How to solve this problem?

I'm local user of this computer and don't have sudo previlege.
I'm already installed imlib2 and lipng to solve this problem.